# $E[(d W_t)^2] =?$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I confused myself here. Let $W_t$ be Brownian motion. It is obvious that the variance of the Brownian motion increment $dW_t$ is $dt$, i.e. $E[(d W_t)^2] = dt$. However, if I write this like so, I get a different result:

\begin{align}
E[(dW_t)^2] &= E[(W_{t+dt} - W_t)^2] \\
&= E[W_{t+dt}^2] - 2E[W_{t+dt}]E[W_t] + E[W_t^2] \\
&= (t+dt) - 0 + t \\
&= 2t + dt
\end{align}

Where is my mistake in the expansion above?

Comment: Since $W_{t+dt}$,$W_t$ are dependent,$E(W_{t+dt}W_t) \ne EW_{t+dt}EW_{t} $  .

Comment: @czxvebiastjuslpgyqm Agh! I missed that they overlap over $t$

Comment: Actually, you should obtain $$-2E(W_{t+dt}\ W_t)= -2\min\{t,t+dt\} = -2t$$ which gives you $dt$ in the end